# How to download .csv data in multiple excel sheets using java script?

Tags: javascript

How to download .csv data in multiple excel sheets using java script.

`data1={"a":"shri","b"="Om"}` should be downloaded in First sheet and

`data1={"a":"Rahul","b"="Ajay"}` should be downloaded in Second sheet and 
there is N:N relations between objects and sheets. It means number of objects equal to number of sheets. Is there any way to create multiple sheets in java script ?

```
`exportCsvTXLS(){
 //here is my conversion logic to put into multiple excel sheet
}`
```

if you have answer using angular js then it is fine as well.
just I want to import multiple objects in multiple sheets.

[image: Here is the simple example of how should I want output. There is two sheets both contains different objects]

Answer (score 0):

I never create Excel file directly in javascript.

You can send your data to your server and you build your Excel file from it. For example, your have an array of object in JSON, then you parse your JSON and build each sheet based on the objects in the array.

The result of the of the query must be the file generated which enable the user to download it.

It will probably be easier to create your Excel file from Java or C# than in Javascript.

Comment: I want it in js or angular.

Comment: I dont want to render it on server side.

Comment: Search for a JS library so... "Excel Javascript" should help you on Google

Comment: You can't build an Excel file by yourself. You will rewrite for nothing what others did. I recommand you greatly to use a library for it.

Comment: If there was only one sheet, you could generate a CSV, but with several sheets you must build an XLS and it is not trivial.